# How can I select a specific element across all rows from a list within a tibble in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble in which one column is a list containing 2x2 matrices.  I want to be able to select a specific element from the matrices across all rows in the tibble.  I am able to select a specific element from one tibble row using indexing:

```
t1 <- tibble(x = 1:2, y = 1, z = x ^ 2 + y)
rM1 <- matrix(c(2,3,1,4), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
rM2 <- matrix(c(10,19,9,15), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
t1$my.lists <- list(rM1,rM2)

t1[[4]][[2]][[2,2]]
[1] 15
```

However when I try to access that specific element across multiple rows I get an error:

```
t1[[4]][1:2][[2,2]]
Error in t1[[4]][1:2][[2, 2]] : incorrect number of subscripts
```

I have also tried using piping and functions such as slice but still haven't been able to acheive the desired result.  In this example I expect a return of:

```
[1]  4 15
```

where 4 is the 2x2 element from rM1 and 15 is the 2x2 element from rM2.  Of course I could write a loop to achieve this but I assume there is also a more direct way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the `list` column number 4, and extract the elements based on row/column index

```
sapply(t1[[4]], function(x) x[2, 2])
#[1]  4 15
```

---

Or with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
t1 %>%
      mutate(new = map_dbl(my.lists, ~ .x[2, 2]))
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#      x     y     z my.lists            new
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <dbl>
#1     1     1     2 <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>     4
#2     2     1     5 <dbl[,2] [2 × 2]>    15
```

---

The OP's code didn't work out because the below is a `list`

```
t1[[4]][1:2]
#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    3
#[2,]    1    4

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   10   19
#[2,]    9   15
```

and the row/column indexing can be done by selecting each `list` element one by one or using a loop

```
t1[[4]][1:2][[2]][2,2]
#[1] 15
```